# Does Might & Magic: Heroes VI include a map editor?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm a big fan of map creation, as well as of playing maps other people have created, but I don't see an option for the map editor on the main menu or on the Conflux menu.  Does a map editor exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sure does! However, unlike in past Heroes games, it's not accessible via the game itself, but rather as a separate program.

[image]

By default, this application is buried deep within the bowels of your steam folder.

If you've used Steam's default install settings, like I have, you should find it here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\might and magic heroes
>   vi

It's the innocuously named "editor" application.

Comment: Thanks - I'm still getting used to Steam.  In previous versions the editor would have been another entry on the Start Menu, so it would have been discoverable that way, rather than spelunking into the game directory for unknown EXEs.